# My eclipse can´t resolved My_menu.xml from res/menu

Tags: java, android, xml, menu

maybe I have stupid question, but I don´t know where is problem. So I have two xlm files in res/menu folder. First call "notes_edit_menu", and second "activity_draw".  But If I want use it in code, like this.

```
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.notes_edit_menu, menu);
        return true;        
    }
```

I can use only "activity_draw". Because "notes_edit_menu", can not be resolved. Other files form res, for example layouts work fine.

Comment: do you have any errors in your resource files?

Answer (score 0):

Okay this can be two things:

1: You imported the wrong R class
Check your imports that you correctly imported your own "package.package.R" and not the android.R.

2: Do a clean build this rebuilds R

Comment: Yes I did it. Others xml files from res are ok. I can´t use onely files from "R.menu.XXX".